# asp label visible false and true in telerik grid depends on combo box selected item

Tags: asp.net, telerik, label, visible

depends on the  selected telerik combox item i would like to display the label name and text box when im writing the code like this in aspx page

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="DeductionCode"   Visible="false" UniqueName="DeductionCode"  HeaderText="DeductionCode">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="false" ID="lblDeductionCode"   Text='<%# Eval("DeductionCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtDeductionCode" Visible = "false" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DeductionCode") %>' MaxLength="2"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ControlToValidate="txtDeductionCode" ID="rfvtxtDeductionCode" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="revtxtDeductionCode" 
                                               ControlToValidate="txtDeductionCode"
                                               ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9'`-´\s]{2}$"
                                               Display="Dynamic"
                                               ErrorMessage="Please Enter 2 charecters only"                                                 
                                              runat="server"
                                              SetFocusOnError="True" />

                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

when im trying to write the on page_load lbldeduction= false the label name is displaying error message..another way i trying to visible false and true in selectedindexed function on compiling time displaying the error like lbldeductioncode is having null value but texbox is working fine like visible false and true..only the problem is i cant able to do the label name visible false and after selected combox item label name visible true..

Answer (score 0):

I found a demo on the Telerik site that can give you a head start with your implementation - take a look at it [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/accessingcellsandrows/defaultcs.aspx).

Dick